# "SQL compilation error: Compilation memory exhausted" for a Snowflake table with 4k columns

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to upload data from parquet file on S3-bucket to Snowflake and facing this error:

```
SQL compilation error:
Compilation memory exhausted.
[SQL: COPY INTO table_name FROM (SELECT $1:col_one::FLOAT, $1:col_two::VARCHAR, ...)

FROM @%source_file.parquet) FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=parquet) PURGE = TRUE
```

The subquery contains about 4200 columns. Increasing the warehouse size from XS to M didn't help. At the same time, loading of about 1000 columns regularly succeeds even for XS warehouse.

I've checked the [query text size](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/query-size-limits.html#limits-on-query-text-size), it's much less than 1 MB.

The source file doesn't contain VARIANT columns, only FLOAT and VARCHAR (quite short).

Comment: If you can't help us reproduce the problem, this seems like a great case to send to support

Answer (score 3):

When you get this error, and you can not reduce the complexity of your query (it seems it's not possible in your case), you should contact Snowflake support.

An important note: Increasing the warehouse size doesn't increase the compilation resources. The compilation is done in Cloud Service Layer. Your warehouses are in the "query processing" layer.